# Starting many Timers at the same time in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, parallel-processing

```
var LevelCode:Array = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,...,990,1000];
var Piece0:Timer = new Timer(50, LevelCode[0]);
var Piece1:Timer = new Timer(50, LevelCode[1]);
...
var Piece98:Timer = new Timer(50, LevelCode[98]);
var Piece99:Timer = new Timer(50, LevelCode[99]);
```

I want to start Piece0 timer, Piece1 timer, etc., at the same time.
I tried `Piece0+Piece1.start();`, but it did not work.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 5):

maybe you don't need many timers, since you're using identical 50 milliseconds timers. 
why don't you just use one timer and handle the event int the function specified with `addEventListener`?

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(50);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerElapsed);
myTimer.start();

function timerElapsed(event:TimerEvent):void 
{
    //handle your levels here
}
```

Comment: They're not totally identical since they repeat different numbers of times, but this does seem like a generally better strategy for synchronizing them.

Comment: You could do this to sync all timers and use currentCount to do different things. But keep in mind that execution time of the timerElapsed() is not part of the 50 milliseconds. Meaning if timerElapsed() takes 5 milliseconds to run, it will be 55 milliseconds between each timer fire. Not sure if this matters to you, but it might make big difference depending on what you want to do in the event listender

Comment: This seems to me like a better solution that having a bunch of timers. Maybe group timers with periods that are multiples/factors of each other, and have a handful (~10) timers as a compromise?

Answer (score 3):

Running

```
Piece0.start();
Piece1.start();
```

Will start them near enough to the same time as to be beneath the threshold that they can resolve, so they'll be effectively the same time.  Starting a timer is not a resource-intensive process.

Comment: I want to do it in one line because there are gonna be 100 Pieces

Comment: In that case I recommend an `Array` of timers and `map()`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to start all 100 of them at the "exact" same time. like @blahdiblah was saying, starting a timer is not a resource intensive process so if you start few of them in a row, they should all start within same milliseconds. however if you want to start 100 of them, you wouldn't be able to start all of them at the same time. You could put them into an array and loop through them to make code more compact but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not rely on timers triggering at the same time like this.
This is a very bad implementation and you need to think about a redesign.
ActionScript is not threaded and as such is asynchronous. 
Because of this no two timer events will ever fire at the same time. 
It will always be one after the other.
 You should follow the suggestion that vulkanino had made and consolidate everything into one call. 
Plus having 100+ timer events is a lot of over head and can you be certain all 100 timer events would be processed in the 50 milliseconds you are giving them to run? 
If not you risk some "overlapping issues" all dependent on the code you are doing in the callback functions.